# Stopping Flex to auto unscape &gt; in xml attributes;

Tags: xml, apache-flex, escaping

I have a xml like this:

```
<test>
    <prueba test="1&gt;2"/>  
    <prueba test="1&lt;2"/>  
</test>
```

When I parse it with XML(), it automatically unescapes >, but not <. The resulting xml  is:

```
  <test>
        <prueba test="1>2"/>  
        <prueba test="1&lt;2"/>  
    </test>
```

I need to prevent this behaviour, because a need the text unescaped. Any idea not involving a previous homemade escaping by replacing the >?

Thanks

Comment: IS this a question about Adobe/Apache Flex?  Can you share the code you're using to parse the XML?

Comment: It's Adobe FLex `var XMLScript : XML = XML(TextFile.read(fichero).replace(new RegExp("\r\n", "g"), "\n"));
`